# Can I add all Junk Mail to Mail's home screen?

Tags: ios, email

In mail I can add views like All Drafts or All Trash to my main menu, but I don't see All Junk Mail. Can I add this to Mail's home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a Mailbox for all Junk mails, and the only option is to create different mailboxes for each of the accounts.